# Theming DialogPreferences

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-theme

I'm using a theme to customize the look and feel of a settings dialog. The preferences are defined in XML and inflated by a `PreferenceFragment`. The way of attaching the fragment is basically as described in the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment).

It works totally fine customizing the first screen via a custom theme applied to the hosting activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Preferences_Dialog);
    ...
```

With the style:

```
<style name="Theme.Preferences.Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#fff0f0f0</item>
    <item name="android:background">#fff0f0f0</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#ffe0e0e0</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff555555</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ff808080</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">@style/preferences_large_text</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/preferences_medium_text</item>
</style>
```

And some preferences defined like:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:title="@string/pref_title" >
...
<ListPreference
    android:enabled="false"
    android:key="@string/pref_change_workspace_key"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:summary="@string/pref_change_workspace_summary_singel"
    android:title="@string/pref_change_workspace_title" />
...
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The trouble is that all preferences that are opening up a dialog (like a `ListPreference`), have a different style than the rest of the dialog.

The first level of the settings fragment looks ok:

[image: Settings first level]

But clicking on one of the elements produces the wrong result:

[image: Settings second level]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seen above results from the line

```
<item name="android:background">#fff0f0f0</item>
```

in the defined style. Apparently this setting is used for the spawned dialog as well. Deleting this line yields the expected result.

Answer (score 5):

values => styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/MyDialogStyle</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/MyDialogStyle</item>

    </style>


    <style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

values-v21 => styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/MyDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/MyDialogStyle</item>

</style>


<style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#fff0f0f0</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

and windowbackground attribute to transparent

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I guess the problem is that these values are not applied to the dialog that opens up.

Comment: use dialogue fragment

Comment: i just declared my theme like this
    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

Comment: I'm already using a dialogue fragment. The problem is not the first level of the settings dialog. The problem is when this dialog contains settings like the ListPreference which open up another dialog, which doesn't seem to get the theme properties from the theme set in the Activity.

Comment: final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(youractivity,R.style.youtheme);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourdialoguexml);
dialog.show();

Comment: If I would open the dialog myself it would work like that, that is true. At the moment I just add the ListPreference as an XML element which automatically opens the dialog for me. I actually wanted to prevent handling the dialog mechanics on my own.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36289/discussion-between-paul-and-user1920666)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I solve my problem using this solution. <item name="android:background">#fff0f0f0</item> does not solve issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to override `android:alertDialogTheme` (supported starting from `API 11`) style property to style preference dialogs (and not only preference but alert dialogs in general too):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">        
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.MyDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```